# Fluent nHibernate, Reverse One-One Property

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I thought this would be pretty simple, but it is proving a bit more frustrating than I anticipated.

Given a structure similar to this ...

```
class Template {
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Attached Attached { get; set; }
}

class Attached {
 public virtual int Id { get; set; }
 public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
}
```

I want the table structure to look like this.

Table - Template

Id

Table - Attached

Id - TemplateId

So I set up my mapping ...

```
class TemplateMap : ClassMap<Template> {
  TemplateMap(){
    HasOne(x => x.Attached).Cascade.All();
  Table("Templates");
  }
}
class AttachedMap : ClassMap<Attached> {
  AttachedMap(){
    References(x => x.Template).Cascade.All().Column("TemplateId");
    Table("Attached");
  }
}
```

then I create a new Template

```
var tmpl = new Template {
  Attached = new Attached {
    // ... 
  }
};

session.SaveOrUpdate(tmpl);
transaction.Commit();
```

But my `TemplateId` in the `Attached` table still comes out Null. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both sides of the relationship here need to be a one to one.  Also you'll need to specify on one side of the relationship that the id is generated foreignly.

Read the following 2 articles if you need more detail:
[link1](http://sdesmedt.wordpress.com/2006/07/24/nhibernate-part-3-mapping-techniques-for-aggregation-one-to-one-mapping/)
[link2](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/951da8c96110d38b)

**Edit:**
Here is an example in Fluent of what I'm talking about and also what they talked about in link1:
[Fluent Example](http://brunoreis.com/tech/fluent-nhibernate-hasone-how-implement-one-to-one-relationship/)

Comment: I'm sorry, those links don't really help much.

Comment: Look at the last link I just posted.  This is a Fluent example so you should be able to see the general idea of what I was talking about and what they mentioned in link1

Comment: Thanks. It appears that what I want to do is just too difficult to accomplish in any simple manner. You would really think this kind of thing would be very rudimentary for nHibernate by now.